# Root element in JSON is coming twice

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson

I am getting twice root element in JSON.

Here is my model:

```
@JsonRootName(value="volumes")
@XmlRootElement(name = "volumes")
public class VolumeDetails {

    @XmlElement(name = "volume")
    private List<VolumeDetail> volume;

    public List<VolumeDetail> getVolumes() {
        if (volume == null) {
             volume = new ArrayList<VolumeDetail>();
        }
        return volume;
    }

}
```

I am using jackson object mapper like:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
try {
    String jsonResponse = om.writeValueAsString(volumeDetails);
    return Response.ok().entity(jsonResponse).build();
}
```

O/P :

```
{
   "volumes":{
      "volumes":[
         {
            "status":"available",
            "id":"vol-1"
         },
         {
            "status":"unavailable",
            "id":"vol-2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Expected O/P:

```
{
        "volumes":[
         {
            "status":"available",
            "id":"vol-1"
         },
         {
            "status":"unavailable",
            "id":"vol-2"
         }
      ]
}
```

volumes tag is coming two times which i don't want, is there any way to suppress it.
if I remove @JsonRootName annotation and serialization features i am getting "volume" instead of "volumes" which is @xmlElement(name="volume") and my output looks like :

```
{
        "volume":[
         {
            "status":"available",
            "id":"vol-1"
         },
         {
            "status":"unavailable",
            "id":"vol-2"
         }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE) documentation:

> Feature that can be enabled to make root value (usually JSON Object but can be any type) wrapped within a single property JSON object, where key as the "root name", as determined by annotation introspector (esp. for JAXB that uses @XmlRootElement.name) or fallback (non-qualified class name). Feature is mostly intended for JAXB compatibility.
>
> Feature is disabled by default.

And [`@JsonRootName`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) documentations:

> Annotation similar to XmlRootElement, used to indicate name to use for root-level wrapping, if wrapping is enabled. Annotation itself does not indicate that wrapping should be used; but if it is, name used for serialization should be name specified here, and deserializer will expect the name as well.

So, considering this example:

```xml
<!-- an old version of jackson which contains "SerializationConfig.Feature" -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName(value = "volumes")
@XmlRootElement(name = "volumes")
public class VolumeDetails {

    @XmlElement(name = "volume")
    private List<VolumeDetail> volume;

    public List<VolumeDetail> getVolumes() {
        if (volume == null) {
            volume = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return volume;
    }

}

public class VolumeDetail {

    private String id;
    private String status;

    // getters and setters

}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final VolumeDetails volumeDetails = new VolumeDetails();

    final VolumeDetail v1 = new VolumeDetail();
    v1.setId("vol-1");
    v1.setStatus("available");
    volumeDetails.getVolumes().add(v1);

    final VolumeDetail v2 = new VolumeDetail();
    v2.setId("vol-2");
    v2.setStatus("unavailable");
    volumeDetails.getVolumes().add(v2);

    final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();// .enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    final String jsonResponse = om.writeValueAsString(volumeDetails);
    System.out.println(jsonResponse);
}
```

Will produce a JSON like this:

```
{
   "volumes":[
      {
         "id":"vol-1",
         "status":"available"
      },
      {
         "id":"vol-1",
         "status":"unavailable"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can just disable `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` from `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: if I remove @JsonRootName annotation and serialization features i am getting "volume" instead of "volumes". I have added the O/P above.

Comment: @chandansingh I update the answer, take a look. Let me now if does't works. If generate `volume` take a look in `VolumeDetails`, maybe you have `getVolume` instead of `getVolumes`.